# GetExtension() fails if filename has invalid characters

Tags: c#

In my C# app I am using `Path.GetExtension()`.

Input to this will depend on file processing. Sometimes my filename could have `myfile-<ID>`. I will process the ID value in a later stage, so I can't remove `<>` while going for checking extension.

`GetExtension()` throws exception of invalid chars. what would be the best way to check if file has extension when `filename` could have invalid chars.

Comment: Can your filename Contain a "." ?

Comment: yes it could contain "."

Comment: If you know what File Extensions you have you could split it at the dots and check if the last appearance is valid.

Comment: Could you clarify this a bit more please? "Here ID value I will be processing in later stage , so I can't remoove <> while going for checking extension."  What is ID and <> ?

Comment: Can you use some other characters instead of `<ID>` for example `(ID)` or `%ID%` or `$ID$`?

Comment: It will be a user specified input so we don't really have control over what user would specify.

Comment: You could implement [the same code as the original `GetExtension`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,287), but remove `CheckInvalidPathChars(path);`

Comment: Replace "<ID>" with an example value, and check the extension of _that_.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you and .Extension, like GetExtension do

```
Dim sPath,sExt As String
sPath  = "c:\namename<2>.RAR"
If sPath.LastIndexOf(CChar(".")) <> -1 
  sExt = sPath.Substring(sPath.LastIndexOf(CChar(".")))
Else
  sExt = Nothing 'no extension?
End if
```

Sorry, you asked for C#

```
string sPath = null;
string sExt = null;
sPath = "c:\\namename<2>.RAR";
if (sPath.LastIndexOf(Convert.ToChar(".")) != -1) {
    sExt = sPath.Substring(sPath.LastIndexOf('.')));
} else {
    sExt = null; //no extension?
}
```

**Edit:**
If there are "."s in path

```
string sPath = null;
string sExt = null;
sPath = "c:\\folder.folder\folder\namename<2>.RAR";

sPath = sPath.Substring(sPath.LastIndexOf('\')));

if (sPath.LastIndexOf('.') != -1) {
    sExt = sPath.Substring(sPath.LastIndexOf('.'));
} else {
    sExt = null; //no extension?
}
```

Comment: 1) Returns incorrect results if the filename contains no `.` but the path does. 2) Why `Convert.ToChar` instead of `'.'`?

Comment: @CodesInChaos, edited 1)well, you can then check for the last '\'. 2) ok, peculiar habits of Vb guys migrating to c# :)

Answer (score 1):

When looking for the extension using the **GetExtension(path)** method, instead of using the path as is, you could use it cleaned up.

Here's an extension method for it:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public static class FileNameExtensions
{
    public static string ToValidPath(this string path)
    {
        return Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()
            .Aggregate(path, (previous, current) => previous.Replace(current.ToString(), string.Empty));
    }
}
```

So you now can call the GetExtension method with the following parameter: **GetExtension(path.ToValidPath())**;